# reordering relabeled data on y axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, categorical-data

I have a dataset that x is a tuple integer:

[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,...40]

and y is a string tuple

['5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '5', '2', '4', '2', '4', '2', '5', '1', '5', '2', '5', '2', '1', '3', '5', '0', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5', '3', '5', '3', '4', '0'].

The y axis data need to be translated to categorical data ('5'->W,'4'->R,'3'->'N1','2'->'N2','1'->'N1'). Zero does not need a label. I chose to plot them as is and just change the label on the y axis:

```
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
conv_tup=np.array(x)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.scatter(conv_tup/2,y)
y_labels={1:'W',2:'N1',3:'N2',4:'N3',5:'R'}
plt.yticks(list(y_labels.keys()), y_labels.values())
plt.show()
```

However, I want to change the order the data is shown on the y axis (not just relabel them) and have this order (from top to bottom y axis): W,R,N1,N2,N3 and plot them both as a scatter plot but as a line plot as well.Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, convert the `y` data to numeric first, which should plot the points in the correct order, and change the yticklabels at the end:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(conv_tup/2, np.array(y).astype(int), '-o')
ax.set_yticks(range(6), ['', 'N3', 'N2', 'N1', 'R', 'W'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Swapping the `1` and `3`:

```
y_star = np.array(y).astype(int)
is_1 = (y_star == 1)
is_3 = (y_star == 3)
y_star[is_1] = 3
y_star[is_3] = 1

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(conv_tup/2, y_star, '-o')
ax.set_yticks(range(6), ['', 'N3', 'N2', 'N1', 'R', 'W'])
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thank you, it is almost there, however your code has W,R,N2 correctly labeled but the data that are labeled as N3 are really the N1 data and vice-versa.

Comment: Hmm. The third-to-last point is '3', which corresponds to N1 if I'm understanding correctly. Your description says '3'->'N1' and from top to bottom, W, R, N1. The plot seems to match that description. What am I missing?

Comment: not sure, I have a larger dataset and it looks that N1 and N3 are swapped. But since it was works in the example I shared I will accept your answer. Thank you very much!!

Comment: If you need them swapped, then flipping the '1' and '3' in `y` should work.